# How to store the value of a buffer in a map and not its reference?

Tags: c++

I have a UDP server which gets messages in a buffer, that I would like to store like a mailbox. For this, I would like to create either a vector or a map that could hold these incoming messages, but the value of my map or vector keeps pointing to the current value of the buffer.

How do I get the values properly stored in a map or vector?

To demonstrate my issue, I've written a simple static example which represents what happens in my script:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char buffer[65535];
    std::map<int, char *> messages;

    buffer = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
    messages[0] = buffer;

    buffer = {'h','o','w'};
    messages[1] = buffer;

    buffer = {'a','r','e'};
    messages[2] = buffer;

    buffer = {'y','o','u'};
    messages[3] = buffer;

    std::cout << messages[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << messages[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << messages[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << messages[3] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The outcome of this is:

```
you
you
you
you
```

But I would like to get:

```
hello
how
are
you
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Just use std::string instead of char*.

Comment: Stop using `char*` for strings and start using `std::string`.

Comment: Also, you forget to put null terminating character, which can result of undefined behavior

Comment: And why a map, instead of vector or list ?

Comment: This should [not even compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/210bdb6f7b84771c)

Comment: Almost an excellent MCVE :P

Comment: Is this an io buffer being parsed after the fact to find different components? If you don't have a null or newline to tell you were the message ends, then you must store the pointer AND length. (or just use the extra memory to store a copy of the message in std::string) As for the pointers being wrong, that's more like this: x=2; x=5; print x; Why is x 5?

Answer (score 9):

If you declare your map with `std::map<int, char *>` the second member is just a pointer to a `char`.

In your code, this pointer points to the first `char` of your `buffer` and you add it several times in your `map` hence you get the same result at the end.

If you want to keep your map with the `char*` you have to allocate some memory to each entry you will add, and at the end free it.

I advise you to replace your `char *` by `std::string` and the manipulations will be way much simpler, as an example :

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::map<int, std::string> messages;
messages[0] = "hello";
messages[1] = "how";
messages[2] = "are";
messages[3] = "you";

std::cout << messages[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << messages[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << messages[2] << std::endl;
std::cout << messages[3] << std::endl;
```

[See on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8af4fe9df2f951e)

Answer (score 0):

What's happening there is that you change the value of the  memory your variable `buffer` points to. If you want to use `char*` then you have to allocate new memory for every message. But as some people in the comment mentioned, you can just use the `std` type `std::string` to do what you want to do. Then the memory management is done behind the scenes

edit: changed the phrase at the beginning, because it was ambiguous!

Comment: *What's happening there is that you change the memory your variable buffer points to* That is not correct.  You cannot change where an array "points to".

Comment: @NathanOliver: But you can change the memory, which is being pointed to; that's how I read it :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I read it that way now.  The first reading to me was was that they where changing the location the array is at.  I guess I was confusing memory with location instead of value.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I think the statement could be fairly read both ways, so it was arguably ambiguous.